# Get Clicked Element Attributes with on("click")

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<ul class="items">
  <li data-val="1">first</li>
  <li data-val="2">second</li>
  <li data-val="3">last</li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
//inside document.ready event
$(".items").find("li").on("click", {value: $(this).data("val") } ,selectNode);

//the function
function selectNode(selected) {
  console.log(selected.data.value);
}
```

I want to get data-val attribute on click event. I know it possible with changing the location of `$(this)` in the function body, but i need to do this outside of the function. I got `undefined` by using `$(this).data("val")` in my code.

Comment: The argument passed to the event handler will be an event object, not the node in question.

Comment: ... and it makes no sense to get the value outside the function. Until the event is triggered, there's no context.

Comment: @Pointy you mean it is impossible to get the value outside the function?

Comment: you want data-val attribute value ? Not data-val attribute itself ?

Comment: If you can create a reference to the `<li>` by some means, you can get the value, but that really doesn't have much to do with setting up the event handler.

Comment: @TusharRaj Yes, i want data-val attribute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an event handler that somehow knows something about the element involved, you can do something like this:

```
$(".items li").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).data("val");
  $(this).on("click", { value: value }, selectNode);
});
```

Your "selectNode" function will have to be different:

```
function selectNode(event) {
  var value = event.data.value;
  console.log("the value is " + value);
}
```

That avoids the use of `this` in the event handler, though it's not at all clear why that would be a problem. Note also that should something else *change* the "val" data property on the element, this approach freezes the value (as far as the event handler is concerned) to what it was at the time the event handler was established.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the only answer that achieves the (inexplicable) requirement of not needing `this` in the event handler.

Comment: Your code is the nearest solution to my question, but i need the attribute value only, because i want to use this function multiple times in different situations

Comment: @SamanGholami What do you mean, "the attribute value only"?  This code does that - the value of `event.data.value` in the event handler will be the value of the "data-val" attribute on the `<li>` element.

Comment: In your solution access to value possible this way : event.data.value , i want call the function with the data-val value, such as selectedNode(1) , selectedNode(2) or etc.

Comment: @SamanGholami That's exactly what this does.  Each `<li>` element is processed separately (that's why it uses `.each()`). Each event handler will be set up such that the "data" property of the event object will have that node's "data-val" value.

Comment: you said it's not at all clear why i want to use function this way, actually i want to use this function in multiple functions and events, is this approach suitable?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine - if you've got lots of different elements with "data-val" attributes, you can use this to set up similar "click" handlers. Of course, the initial selector would have to be different, but other than that this will make the event objects always look the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$(this)` - in parent context, not in selected node context, use code like this:

```
var li = $(".items").find("li");
li.on("click", {value: li.data("val") } ,selectNode);

//the function
function selectNode(selected) {
  console.log(selected.data.value);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why, but the OP apparently doesn't want to use `$(this)` to get at the element.

Comment: @Pointy, oh, yes. I change answer.

Comment: @maximkou li.data("val") always returns '1' if your are click any li elements

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this, appart from the fact it (should) work, it only creates one eventHandler insteadt of 3 (the count of li's)

```
$(".items").on("click", "li" ,function(){
  console.log($(this).data.value);
});
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i know this way, but i don't want to use it.

Comment: Then just use a closure as shown in "Milind Anantwar" example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/dm7gc2t5/

```
//inside document.ready event
$(".items").find("li").on("click", function selectNode(e) {
console.log($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
```